# how to use a possible case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm learning SQL and have a question with my build. Here's what I have built:

```
SELECT 
[System],
[CPU%],
[Boot and Login Time(Minutes)],
[System Uptime(s)],
SUM([Boot and Login Time(Minutes)]) AS [Total Time Consumed By the System]

FROM 
(
SELECT 
T0.ID AS [System],
INT_CPU+DPC_CPU AS [CPU%],
T1.MAINPATH/60000 AS [Boot and Login Time(Minutes)],
T2.UPTIME_SEC AS [System Uptime(s)]
FROM TABLE1 AS T0
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS T1 ON T0.ID=T1.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 AS T2 ON T0.ID=T2.ID
) AS T0
WHERE [CPU%] > 30 AND [Boot and Login Time(Minutes)] > 5
GROUP BY 
[System],
[CPU%],
[Boot and Login Time(Minutes)],
[System Uptime(s)]
```

The complete result of this code depends on the WHERE Clause(WHERE [CPU%] > 30 AND [Boot and Login Time(Minutes)] > 5). However, I want the result to be something different.

I want the result for these 3 from the SELECT statement to be based on the WHERE CLAUSE:

```
[System],
[CPU%],
[Boot and Login Time(Minutes)]
```

These other 2 from the SELECT statement should not be dependent on the where clause. Meaning their should be a result for these 2 regardless of the WHERE condition being met:

```
[System Uptime(s)],
SUM([Boot and Login Time(Minutes)]) AS [Total Time Consumed By the System]
```

How can I edit the code. Could I make use of case statement? I tried and it got confusing.

Also, how do we convert MIPS into PERCENTAGE. I have a column that gives me TOTALCPU MIPS and want to use this in the code but in the form of percentage. Example, I have these values in my TOTAL CPU Column:

```
1623453.66897
0
0
2148441.01573933
3048946.946314
```

I want to convert these values into percentage and use them. I couldn't find much info on the internet.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  You are filtering on two columns -- and those same columns are used as `GROUP BY` keys.

That means that the `WHERE` is filtering entire *rows* in the final result set.  It is not changing the values of the `SUM()`.

In fact, it is rather strange to have logic like this:

```
SELECT . . .,
       SUM([Boot and Login Time(Minutes)])
FROM . . .
GROUP BY . . ., SUM([Boot and Login Time(Minutes)]);
```

I would not expect `[Boot and Login Time(Minutes)]` in the `GROUP BY`.  Why would you want different rows on different values if you are also taking the sum?  There may be some rare occasions where that is what you want.  If so, it is clearer to write:

```
[Boot and Login Time(Minutes)] * COUNT(*)
```